# Python application directory strucuture (Linux)

Tags: python, installation, package, dir

What is the best practice to structure the python application when installed to the system as a rpm/deb package?
The app code is mostly written in Python, and there are some shell scripts, configuration files and log files.

I was thinking to have the structure as below.

- Where to put the Python package?
- I need to have the config file for the app, but it would be used by the Python package. Where to put the config file?

> /opt/.../app_name-1.0.0/
>
> ```
>                   bin/
>                       /*Here would be few shell scripts I need*/
>                       shell_script_1.sh
>                       shell_script_2.sh
>
>                    var/
>                        log/
>                           /* Log files */
>                           app_name.log
>                        notifications/
>                                     /* notifications, generated by app,
>                                        temporarily kept */
>                                     alert_1.tmp
>                                     alert_2.tmp 
>
>                    etc/
>                        /*python package configuration*/
>                        /*is it better to put this in package dir?*/
>                        app_name.config 
>
>                    app_name/
>                            /*Python package, the main content*/
>                             __init__.py
>                             app_name.py
>                             a.py
>                             b.py
>                             config_file_reader.py
>
>                             subpackage_1/                  
>                                           __init__.py
>                                           c.py
>                             subpackage_2/                  
>                                           __init__.py
>                                           d.py
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the config file in the home directory, many applications do this (eg bash, vim...)

Comment: Yes, that's also OK I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Putting python code to standard python dir would be the best.(e.g. /usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages).
Unfortunately I have the requirement to put the source insde tha app dir, so I will put to what I think is the second best place:
/opt/.../app_name-1.0.0/lib/python/app_name/

and config file goes to etc/

Well, I am not sure how this conforms to standard, but seemingly good enough for me.